# Converting STR to INT on Dataframe doesn't work on the specific parts

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, anaconda, spyder

I know, this is an easy question, but I checked so many sites on the internet and couldn't find the problem that I have.

I have a dataframe and one column of this dataframe is for brand. I wanted to give specific numbers for these brands to make brand aggregation easier.

```
import pandas as pd

last = pd.read_pickle('pre_clustering.pkl')

random_number=9288
first=""
f=0
for i in last['brand']:
    
    if(type(i)==str):
        if(first == i):
            last.at[f, 'brand']= random_number
            print(last.loc[f, 'brand'])
            f=f+1
            
            
        elif(first !=i):
            first=i
            random_number= random_number +1
            last.at[f, 'brand'] = random_number
            print(last.loc[f, 'brand'])
            f=f+1
           
    else:
        f=f+1
    
brand = last['brand']
```

[This is my code and output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmwuB.png)
I tried everthing to convert them to integer, but they are still string. I controlled my if else condition to be sure by using print() and it is [working as you see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T20Md.png)

What is wrong with my code? or what should I do to convert my strings to integers?

Comment: Please, add your code as a text in your question.

Comment: I edited, sorry I'm newbie on this platform, thought just image could be enough.@Nour-AllahHussein

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you use a sequence of `f` as an index of rows in `last`, but `last` is sorted on `brand`, therefore the sequence of `f` is not the index of row. as a result, you put the random number in the wrong places and leave others.

In order to correct code, we use `last.iterrows()` in `for loop` as follows:

```
for f, row in last.iterrows():
    i=row['brans']
```

where `f` will be the index of the row you dealing with, so you do not need `f=f+1`.

and `i` holds the `brand` in the row you deal with.

Finally, I added some declaration as `(comment)` with modification of your code:

```
import pandas as pd

last = pd.read_pickle('pre_clustering.pkl')

random_number=9288
first=""
# f=0 (No need)
for f, row in last.iterrows():  # for i in last['brand']:  (Changed: f is the actual row index)
    i=row['brand'] # (added)

    if(type(i)==str):
        if(first == i):
            last.at[f, 'brand']= random_number
            print(last.loc[f, 'brand'])
            # f=f+1   (No need)
            
        elif (first !=i): 
            first=i
            random_number= random_number +1
            last.at[f, 'brand'] = random_number
            print(last.loc[f, 'brand'])
            # f=f+1
           
    #else:
    #    f=f+1
    
brand = last['brand']
```

Do your best :)

Comment: Awww, thank you so much! Now I got the point which I was wrong on. :>

Answer (score 0):

Did you try typecasting ? with the use of `as.type('int')`  . More details here : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html

Comment: I already tried it and my problem is not with this guessing and had another answer which is correct. If you want, you should check it. Btw thanks for your effort too!